# Devise : Using Devise Oauth info for facebook interactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I have gotten Oauth working with Devise and my users are happily logging in  using their Facebook accounts. I would like to allow the users to "like" certain things on my site and post stuff back to their profiles. How do I do that using the information I have (seemingly only an encrypted_password and password_salt)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I request offline_access permission from Facebook. Every time when the user login, I store his Facebook access_token (graph API) to our user record. So we can use the access_token to post something to user's Facebook wall anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You need the stream_publish permission and you should check the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post) on how to do this. In order to allow users to 'like' content on your site you should use the appropriate opengraph meta tags on your content, as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph).

Comment: Don't I need some kind of token to pass to FB? All Devise is storing currently is the encrypted password and salt.